# mkvirtualenv: command not found and how to know if virtualenvwrapper is correct installed

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I installed `virtualenvwrapper` with `pip` and I got this:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenvwrapper in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv-clone in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stevedore in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pbr>=1.6 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.9.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
```

I added the next lines to my `.bashrc` file

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR=$WORKON_HOME/hooks
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

After editing it, I restarted the terminal and tried to create my virtual environment with `mkvirtualenv` but I got this error:

```
mkvirtualenv: command not found
```

Looking for the answer I read I should run the which `virtualenvwrapper` command to know where this was installed. I did it but I get just nothing.

Please, can you help me? I can't go on and I really need to do it.

The answers that I found only say about the lines I have to add to  the `.bashrc` file to solve the problem.

Comment: Are you sure your .bashrc is being read? What does `echo $WORKON_HOME` show?

Comment: Hi, I get nothing with echo $WORKON_HOME

Comment: So, evidently, your .bashrc is not actually being read. Debugging that is outside the scope of StackOverflow; maybe try on unix.se, askubuntu, or apple.se.

Comment: // , What research have you done on this already?

Comment: // , How would we reproduce the issue? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask